# Do I have a twin with permutated remainders?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, number-theory

We define \$R_n\$ as the list of remainders of the Euclidean division of \$n\$ by \$2\$, \$3\$, \$5\$ and \$7\$.

Given an integer \$n\ge0\$, you have to figure out if there exists an integer \$0<k<210\$ such that \$R_{n+k}\$ is a permutation of \$R_n\$.

### Examples

The criterion is met for \$n=8\$, because:

- we have \$R_8=(0,2,3,1)\$
- for \$k=44\$, we have \$R_{n+k}=R_{52}=(0,1,2,3)\$, which is a permutation of \$R_8\$

The criterion is not met for \$n=48\$, because:

- we have \$R_{48}=(0,0,3,6)\$
- the smallest integer \$k>0\$ such that \$R_{n+k}\$ is a permutation of \$R_{48}\$ is \$k=210\$ (leading to \$R_{258}=(0,0,3,6)\$ as well)

### Rules

- You may either output a truthy value if \$k\$ exists and a falsy value otherwise, or two distinct and consistent values of your choice.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Hint

> *Do you really need to compute \$k\$? Well, maybe. Or maybe not.*

### Test cases

Some values of \$n\$ for which \$k\$ exists:

```
3, 4, 5, 8, 30, 100, 200, 2019
```

Some values of \$n\$ for which \$k\$ does not exist:

```
0, 1, 2, 13, 19, 48, 210, 1999
```

Answer (score 22):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>63</s> <s>59</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```r
\(n,a=c(2,3,5,7))any(diff(s<-n%%a)&s[-1]<a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dc9LCsIwEAbgfU8xVCoJTqHpA1tpj6Eb62KoiQqlSBMXPYubCnooj-ENTGk3Ki7yB2YmfJnrre3vCgp4XIzy0-eiZA1SUbEQI0xwyTk1HduflGI69xvPIz7XW1_scuLTk9cM1poO0lEsTrnjzGAj25PqgOoaTHsxxw6M1AYq0lI7FRnmThM_3ZWLoOl8rjtWsQghRkgQUoQoQBCBjXAMkXEEZY9bNu43qqjW8i_60_1AB8cCNi0vMvsFq4diKGfZiE6L9_14vwE)

-4 bytes thanks to Giuseppe 
-13 bytes by switching to `diff` 
-3 bytes inspired by a suggestion from Dominic van Essen

(The explanation contains a spoiler as to how to solve the problem without computing \$k\$.)

Explanation:
Let \$s\$ be the list of remainders. Note the constraint that s[1]<2, s[2]<3, s[3]<5 and s[4]<7. By the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), there exists a \$k\$ iff there is a permutation of \$s\$, distinct from \$s\$, which verifies the constraint. In practice, this will be verified if one of the following conditions is verified:

- s[2]<2 and s[2]!=s[1]
- s[3]<3 and s[3]!=s[2]
- s[4]<5 and s[4]!=s[3]

Comment: Could you explain why the permutation is necessarily distinct from \$s\$?

Comment: @dfeuer It is a consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem; I added a link. If two integers have the same remainders modulo 2, 3, 5 and 7 (without a permutation), then the two integers are equal modulo 2*3*5*7=210.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dc9BCsIwEAXQfU8xVJQJTKBpLbZSj6EbdRFiooVSpImLnsVNBT2Ux_AGprQbFRf5gZkJL3O9Nd3dwAoeF2d49uQ7rJmsWzyUxqAteD2dKiwLrjCmhFJGC8ZmdsvFvijZ-Og1gbWVRx0YnGcsCCaw0U1pWpBVBa65uFMLTlsHSlptAyUdhuPET3cZElh5PlctKkwI5gQpQUaQRAQi8hEPIXJGYPwJd3X4jRpZWf0X_el-oL3jAZ-eF7n_gtdj0ZfzfEDHxbtuuN8)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks! I'm actually down to 43 now, with a change that is related to your suggestion (and which generates a warning).

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 69 bytes

Based on the Chinese remainder theorem

```hs
m=[2,3,5,7]
f x|s<-mod x<$>m=or[m!!a>b|a<-[0..2],b<-drop a s,s!!a/=b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hco7DoQgEADQfk8xJpaD35htwIsQiiFKJDJiwMLCu7Mb6/c2yvsaQims9IAjTvg1Hwf3k6XguMAt65lVTJqrimb7kBS6a5rBoJViSfEEgoz5j62ypjD5Q53JH1ftfLjWBO7tfWfKDw)

Comment: Actually, my working title for this challenge was _"Do I have a Chinese twin?"_ :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>64</s> <s>61</s> <s>59</s> 43 bytes

```perl6
{map($!=(*X%2,3,5,7).Bag,^209+$_+1)∋.&$!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/OjexQENF0VZDK0LVSMdYx1THXFPPKTFdJ87IwFJbJV7bUPNRR7eemopi7f@0/CIFYx0FEx0FUx0FCx0FYwMdBUMDIGEEIQwtFaq5FIoTKxWUVOJtlXQUivOBlmioxGtac9VyAcU1gAyQISB9QAQ0y9ASaB7QKCNDkAkgviU@Q/4DAA)

-16 thanks to @Jo King

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>125</s> <s>42</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```cs
n=>n%7<5&5<n%35|n%5<3&3<n%15|-~n%6>3
```

Direct port of @xnor's answer, which is based off of @RobinRyder's solution.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Ørjan Johansen!

Saved 2 more thanks to @Arnauld!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY0xC4MwEIV3f8UhKAonGGPaWqNjp@4dSgcbIg2UEzRtB7V/3SZ0@e7dx4OnpkxNZju9SElDFu/D8Gz7ZqOmpWgvRSwkRVwsFAnJY@4eJpbsS9Gu5Vsd9MOoO/VI3t0IVk8WDAHpz/U2c4QSQSAcEHiOwHKH4g9WIXjlsqNrelG6YsG8rqpqTYM5uIzG6rMhnYRzvh5hZmuIfgX7xJ80rYN1@wE)

Comment: I found a variation that only ties for xnor's languages but helps for this: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY1NC4JAFEX3/oqHoCg8acZxKvNj2ap9i2hRw0gD8QS1Woz2122GNufdd7hw1Zip0azHF6na0IT3vn@2XbNS01K0q2Usa4qEnCmStYiFe7icsy9F203RsrUKun7QN/VI3rcBJj1OYAhIfy5XKxAKBImwRxAMgTOH/A9eInjlsqNrelG4Ys69LstySQMbnAcz6ZMhnYSWLQewfAnRr2CX@JOmVbCsPw "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: Isn't `-~n%6/4>0` just `-~n%6>3`?

Comment: BTW, this is a [JavaScript polyglot](https://tio.run/##JYpBDoIwEEX3nGI2JZAMhDJUbVK4iHHRIBgNTokYV8Sr12ncvPz/8h7@47fxdV/fFYfrFOc@cj@wOjqTG8eKzM7KOMpJjjZ79WV1GCiOgbewTPUSbkUGcCaEDsEgnBCoQdCNoP1DW4SkZAulTKKTsNVJW2sv9dOvxVxmZfwB).

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

```hs
g.mod
g r|let p?q=r p/=r q&&r q<p=2?3||3?5||5?7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRBDoIwEAXQvaf4C8POSiDEmNj0IMqiwbY2DjiULufsDrzF@/jtG4g02pcmM//ep4QiFCrYrbaAr0dr0xw92HauF@ndIDK4m84@L7DgkpeKM2KmGgoinq0xXXsf9T9F8mnTy8S8Aw)

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: @dfeuer It's using Robin Ryder's method.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 67 bytes

```
!FreeQ[Sort/@Table[R[#+k],{k,209}],Sort@R@#]&
R@n_:=n~Mod~{2,3,5,7}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYu9CsIwGEX3PkWk4OIH@bNohEImN0GjWykSNdRSm0LIFtJXjykuLmc4955R@7cZte@fOnV1Wh2dMZfmOjmP5U0/PqZRTbkZWggDMCJiC8smlSzbdaGkvR9qO5@m1xwYcKhgF9PZ9dYjLDssAwe0BVQB2gPiBBAlGewHKmLx/13m7DNzRUUuc8ToooUQMaUv)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%5!=n%7<5or n%3!=n%5<3or-~n%6/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LdLLbhNBEIXhfZ7CLCzF0kH0qb6j@EkCC1tgYgkmkZUNG17d/I1YjDRTU9Uz5@t@@/3@8rrF/XL8cv95@nX@dtptn7d9/XDc9v2pvt522z6vh/qUX28f/2z79qncT8fnrKKqpq6hKSfZcshFrnKTuzwUSWFFKLKiKKqiKbqCV1M5KVs5lLNyUa7KTbkrT5WkYpVQ4UNFpao0lamaVK0aqlm1qjbVrjpUp1pSy2pFjf9qal1tqid1q4d6Vedvu/pQnxpJwxqhUTSqRtMgCVGsGZpZs2hWzabZNamvjIRMpEzETIRMpPwXnNqK7sxF/gWwBBYBBjazQDiWEH1YGAyjYTiMhwExIobEmBgUo2JYjIuBMTLGxcC4LGrqqLisOvPwGB8DZHhc117QA5JRMkzGyUC50dNYAzFD5rY2jb5GD2zGzcAZOUPnvnaUNdAzah7MQWfsDJ7H2m7mJnMYGkSjaAwNolE0jMYxcAwcA8dInIvEwcAz8IzE2Ujj68PD@fi87S7r/O2u2@522n58fwynw/WyuzxuBzrebtft/fF0PJ4P/@/Ph/tf)

Uses the same characterization as [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182676/20260). The check `n%2!=n%3<2` is shortened to `-~n%6/4`. Writing out the three conditions turned out shorter than writing a general one:

**46 bytes**

```python
lambda n:any(n%p!=n%(p+1|1)<p for p in[2,3,5])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LdLLahtBEIXhvZ9CWRgkchZ9qu8hehLFC4lEiSAZD8IbQ95d@cdkMTD0VPX0@brW97dfr0s8rsdvj9/nP5fv593y5by875fn9dNxed6vn/3Xh6/r7vp6362723IKZdWXw@N8PGUVVTV1DU05yZZDLnKVm9zloUgKK0KRFUVRFU3RFXyayknZyuyalYtyVW7KXXmqJBWrhAo/KipVpalM1aRq1VDlJFW1qXbVoTrVklpWK2qcq6l1tame1K0e6lWd03b1oT41koY1QqNoVI2mQRKiWDM0s2bRrJpNs2uyvmUkZCJlImYiZCLlR3DWtujOPOTfADaBjQADm14gHJsQdVgYDKNhOIyHATEihsSYGBSjYliMi4ExMsbFwLhs1Kyj4rKt0w@P8TFAhsd1uwtqQDJKhsk4GSg3ahp7IGbI3LZLo65RA5txM3BGztC5bzfKHugZNQ/6oDN2Bs9ju276Jn0YGkSjaAwNolE0jMYxcAwcA8dIzEViMPAMPCMxG2m8PD1djqflY/AWBm93Py8/f@zD6XC77q775UDFer8tb/vz8Xg5/H@/HB7/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```ruby
->n{[2,3,5,7].each_cons(2).any?{|l,h|n%l!=n%h&&n%h<l}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3fCoIwFMbvfYrThVpxEt2UEpo9yBhhongxTpF5IduefW0IHz/4/sD3XV@bn4S/dGQkQ44NXlUx9sP8HN60HNmp6Gl7GKtxtpTqg6B0zrKAu3bOS45QIzQINwReIlRlANtRtQgxCgqz6OqwYlUso2/b/QkMWLLJZ/0tIAknSUqdcxAd5Inzfw)

Uses [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182676/6828)'s clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 36 bytes

```java
n->n%7<5&5<n%35|n%5<3&3<n%15|-~n%6>3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9La4NAEL77K4bABi2rxOi2NTG591Ao5Fhy2PoIa3UVdwyUxv51O6shC/MNM/M92EpepV/l35NqurZHqGgOBlR1UA46Q9Xq4GnvZLU0Bt6l0vDrAHTDV60yMCiR2rVVOTR0c0/YK335PIPsL8abqQBvGj/6IleZxAJKOEzaP2r2koq1SDWLxE0zkUbriIZQ3Pw/zZ6P0bSftUojuWFh0MDh7mdfxCHmIDi8cog2HMINwXaBMOEPnj3RjpAUdICYBNvQrpMkudPGJatse5fy5rTdkuk9Ik8/BosmaAcMOvojlu6KxfkOmGF6xWc2hzKw3bXgeYvp6Ngap38)

### Credits

- Port of xnor's solution, improved by Ørjan Johansen.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 56 bytes

```
Or@@(Min[s-#]>0&/@Rest@Permutations@Mod[#,s={2,3,5,7}])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxCoMwFEX3fsUDQVp4RZNU2gyW9wNS6SoOoQ3qEAWTTpJvT5906XKGe89xJozWmTC9TBrq9FiJjs00d/6c9fcyL@hpfaDWru4T2FpmT83y7jL09SZRYYXX2J/y1K7THKCgoaBNIVwQKoQbgioRRMmQPwgdD//ufvPO5EpoLjmSYp@11jGlLw)

Finds all non-identity permutations of the remainders of the input modulo 2, 3, 5, 7, and checks if any of them are below `{2,3,5,7}` in each coordinate. Note that `Or@@{}` is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>81</del> <del>78</del> 72 bytes

```php
while($y<3)if($argn%($u='235'[$y])!=($b=$argn%'357'[$y++])&$b<$u)die(T);
```

A riff on [@Robin Ryder's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182676/84624) answer.  Input is via `STDIN`, output is `'T'` if truthy, and empty `''` if falsy.

```php
$ echo 3|php -nF euc.php
T
$ echo 5|php -nF euc.php
T
$ echo 2019|php -nF euc.php
T
$ echo 0|php -nF euc.php

$ echo 2|php -nF euc.php

$ echo 1999|php -nF euc.php
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctBC4IwGIDhv7Lgq31DwmhIgRtdIujSJW8hoTjnwOaYjvDXr6zr8/K6zkVxcp0jyvvBP71yg5@M1bhjOYHKa0skabWaRrwX5@vtq2lKRvMKfTUpspxbe4nvzvQKYRacmRZ/3xohSLrnGX3AXLKVRKjlv1CeHRZNkpJtoBYQWGMUFiyP8fgB)

#### Or 73 bytes with `1` or `0` response

`while($y<3)$r|=$argn%($u='235'[$y])!=($b=$argn%'357'[$y++])&$b<$u;echo$r;`

```php
$ echo 2019|php -nF euc.php
1
$ echo 1999|php -nF euc.php
0
```

[Try it online (all test cases)!](https://tio.run/##LY5Ba4NAEIXP3V8xDdO6koWoG2ntKj0VeigkdyvBhE0MhCjjSpG2v93O1lwezPtm3puu6ab8tWs6sEQt7ch2Lbnz9SSj0AiBzvauhwJKAVCCVrBWkCp4VqAjBXHEkswSZwruVitwNFhe9pRtVj7ybM03SeztLMug8qvH@tJbUXHPsSVbHxoJc2EZVVD3gDWdrhDCN@ch8Rc4skSGR3to2pkrWLx8uoWZvprzxUoccx0i/RT/8EHiUASJToMSxyq8LyTubyTQ6ZN3l8sqfMR9joPxoUhmusVv37e7t82HEb9i@gM)

#### Original answer, <del>133</del> 127 bytes

```php
function($n){while(++$k<210)if(($r=function($n){foreach([2,3,5,7]as$d)$o[]=$n%$d;sort($o);return$o;})($n+$k)==$r($n))return 1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9Ba8JAEIXPza94lS3ZxQUTrbS6BvHQ0oJQwWMaJOimCZVs2Ky0IP72dBLtoYdSehmYmffme1PlVTObV3kFba2xG6srY11RvvFAKLAsarJDuXWFKTkrxfEjL/aa9/vsfTYMA1FknDMb/ZBkxup0m/N4KEdyLO@StGY7wUycRKy8YTtVE4AzI5TV7mBLZtRJkJNuiihitj0iziuE6tQoz2NO165GhNgDYowkbiXGEvcSo0AiDKgMzyWcIJG4Ggzg7EF38lZBK6pkDCdkJh@lb5sJyVtxlu5r7SXEujjRIb3vZ3COEAcJ0poaCBzpuN7mhjqJ3vTV9STYJ4VkGe8UNP0ezuGvFuu1jyn8x8Xz0pdYPa02Dy9L5Z06ZhfgF2j4L@iFev0XtvkC)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 72 bytes

```r
n=scan();b=c(2,3,5,7);for(i in n+1:209)F=F|all(sort(n%%b)==sort(i%%b));F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOsk2WcNIx1jHVMdc0zotv0gjUyEzTyFP29DKyMBS083WrSYxJ0ejOL@oRCNPVTVJ09YWzM4EsTWt3f4b/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
8ÆR©PḶ+%Ṣ¥€®ċḢ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/icFvQoZUBD3ds01Z9uHPRoaWPmtYcWnek@@GORSr/rQ@3cx1uB4q4//9vrGOiY6pjoWNsoGNoYKBjBMaGljpAro6RjqGxDpBtYqFjZAgUsLS0BAA)

I’m sure there’s a golfier answer. I’ve interpreted a truthy value as being anything that isn’t zero, so here it’s the number of possible values of k. If it needs to be two distinct values that costs me a further byte.

#### Explanation

```
8ÆR             | Primes less than 8 [2,3,5,7]
   ©            | Copy to register
    P           | Product [210]
     Ḷ          | Lowered range [0, 1, ..., 208, 209]
      +         | Add to input
         ¥€     | For each of these 210 numbers...
       %   ®    |   Modulo 2, 3, 5, 7
        Ṣ       |   And sort
            ċḢ$ | Count how many match the first (input) number’s remainders
```

Comment: All good regarding truthy vs falsey. Using the meta agreed definition of truthy and falsey (effectively "what does the language's if-else construct do if there is one) zero is falsey and non-zeros are truthy (`?` is the if-else construct in Jelly; for some languages it's a harder question).

Comment: Oh, and you could get distinct values for no cost with `Ḣe$` if you wanted :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes of course, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda x:int('4LR2991ODO5GS2974QWH22YTLL3E3I6TDADQG87I0',36)&1<<x%210
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNC4JAGIT/ynup1djA3fVrQ4PAMEEIS4hQD0YtCaViHjbE324rXR5mhplpv/2zqdkk/Hx6le/bvQS5qepeQ2Z8opyTY3C0wjPljplcDpRe0zhmexbZabALktB1IgNhZutL4nlyQYkxtd08X2UCDXKE9RYGoUl9RCCaDiRUNWQMg4nBwuBiYAYGYijQPwjHMEdKK6rmHJiqqL5nw3lR4M@j9VFeI336AQ)

Hardcoded

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ƶ.L+ε‚ε4Åp%{}Ë}à
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//8a1LkwrzrXigJrOtTTDhXAle33Di33DoP//MjAxOQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeXhCqL2SwqO2SQpK9v@PbdXz0T63NeJRw6xzW00OtxaoVtce7q49vOC/zv9oYx0THVMdCx1jAx1DAwMdIzA2tNRRAPJ1jHQMjXWAHBMLHSNDoIClpWUsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ƶ.L          # Create a list in the range [1,209] (which is k)
   +         # Add the (implicit) input to each (which is n+k)
    ε        # Map each value to:
     ‚       #  Pair it with the (implicit) input
      ε      #  Map both to:
       4Åp   #   Get the first 4 primes: [2,3,5,7]
          %  #   Modulo the current number by each of these four (now we have R_n and R_n+k)
           { #   Sort the list
      }Ë     #  After the inner map: check if both sorted lists are equal
     }à      # After the outer map: check if any are truthy by taking the maximum
             # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶ.` is `209`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
1 e.(>:+i.@209)-:&(/:~)&(2 3 5 7&|"1 0)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxCsIwFIXhvU/x0yFN0MbcpGJvwCIITk7uTtKiLr6A@OoxODn8y/nOs7S@W9hnOtYEcq33HC/nUxFmb6e8evhDDOr6bOwmf5yxkcSWnXm3QnDX4hqa@XZ/sWCmakPVkRSQEIi/RP8eFYhIQpRhJEodVJXyBQ)

Brute force...